# Iterate through Java List with thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, list, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Im trying to work with Thymeleaf.

How can I iterate through a list of Strings with thymeleaf?

I use Spring Boot.

Thanks for your answers!

```
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(Model model) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add("Test1");
        list.add("Test2");

        return "hello.html";

    }
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <th:block th:each="element : ${list}">
        <tr>
            <td th:text="${list[1]}">...</td>
            <td th:text="${list[2]}">...</td>
        </tr>
    </th:block>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<tr><th:block th:each="element : ${list}"><td th:text="${ellement}">...</td></th:block></tr>`. Alternatively, if each value should be in its own row, move the `<tr>` inside the `<h:block...>`

Comment: You can find the official documentation [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#iteration) with good examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render a list using Thymeleaf, first you should inject the list using the model object.

Add the following lines on your controller:

```
model.addAttribute("list", list);
```

Now, edit your html as follows:

```
<tr th:each="element : ${list}">
  <td th:text="${element}"></td>
</tr>
```

You should see your list elements injected in the view.

Comment: Thank you! :) How can I do this with a List of Objects? Like "List<User>" and User stores (name, prename, id)